# OS X transparent panels in Qt?

Tags: cocoa, macos, qt, qt4

Is there a way to create a transparent panel as described by the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW24) in Qt 4.6 (built for OS X 10.6/Cocoa)?

If not, are there any alternatives similar in look and function?

I understand that Qt is a cross platform toolkit, but I want my application to feel as "native" as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried on Mac, but this should be possible.  Here's what the [QWidget docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html) say:

> Creating Translucent Windows
>
> Since Qt 4.5, it has been possible to create windows with translucent regions on window systems that support compositing.
>
> To enable this feature in a top-level widget, set its `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute with `setAttribute()` and ensure that its background is painted with non-opaque colors in the regions you want to be partially transparent.
>
> Platform notes:
>
> X11: This feature relies on the use of an X server that supports ARGB visuals and a compositing window manager.
>
> Windows: The widget needs to have the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` window flag set for the translucency to work.

I imagine your panel is a top-level widget, so make sure to set `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` as directed in the above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am really looking for a way to create Cocoa »transparent panels« as described/depicted in the linked part of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: I don't know much about Mac. Can you explain the difference between the two?

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed your response. The difference is illustrated in Figure 14-1 of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines linked in the original question. I have not checked the source code yet, but I'm afraid Qt simply does not support this platform-dependent alternative widget set, since I have not found any references to it in the docs.