# Qt Quick / New Open GL API - Transparent Panels in OSX and similar

Tags: opengl, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols, qt5.4

My question is conceptually similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568457/os-x-transparent-panels-in-qt). But that question is targeted at the old `QWidget` API while I am asking about Qt's new Open GL (`QWindow`) API.

So how can I enable the transparency of Panels on `QWindow` and especially `QtQuick` applications using `QtQuick.Controls`?

Comment: Could something like [this](http://goo.gl/sUGxY3) be of interest?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Sorry for the late answer. No, that would only make the entire window transparent.

Comment: Sure,  since opacity is zero.  Does a different value provide a suitable result?

Comment: You don't understand my question. Some OS X Standard Components are semi-transparent and I wanted to achieve the same native effect with `Qt.Quick.Controls`.

Comment: I did. That was part of a solution for translucency, I've found googling. Couldn't try it since it doesn't work on Windows and my mac was at work. I just needed a feedback. That's it.  Things changed on Monday...I'll post the link asap if could help.